# Combining several WHERE clauses in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I have the following php-code which works fine:

```
$sql="UPDATE `fa` SET `group` = '27',`locked` = '1'  WHERE `send` LIKE '%Amazon%' AND `Locked` =0";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$sql="UPDATE `fa` SET `group` = '27',`locked` = '1'  WHERE `send` LIKE '%ebay%' AND `Locked` =0";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$sql="UPDATE `fa` SET `group` = '27',`locked` = '1'  WHERE `send` LIKE '%google%' AND `Locked` =0";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

Is there a way to put those lines into one line? 
Just to clean up the code.

Comment: use OR ex. ``WHERE (`send` LIKE '%Amazon%' OR `send` LIKE '%ebay%')``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `OR`:

```
update `fa`
set `group` = '27',
    `locked` = '1'
where (
        `send` like '%Amazon%'
        or `send` like '%ebay%'
        or `send` like '%google%'
        )
    and `Locked` = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `OR` and `AND` together.

```
WHERE (`send` LIKE '%Amazon%' OR `send` LIKE '%ebay%' OR `send` LIKE '%google%') AND `Locked` =0
```

Learn: [Combining the AND and OR Conditions](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/and_or.php)